# How do you make a block kill you in Minecraft 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a block kill you when you touch it using command blocks in 1.13.

I tried using answers, but when I put `/execute`, it's white, and when I put `/execute @p` it's red.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you specifically want to kill players that are standing on a block? Or do you want to also get anyone who collides in any way with a block (does touching it from the side count)

Comment: I want it to kill players that are standing on the block

Comment: Make it a redstone ore block, with observer beneath, and plenty of TNT under that.

Answer (score 3):

Run command:

```
execute as @a[distance=..1] run kill @s
```

or:

```
execute as @a at @s if block {name block} run kill @s
```

Comment: I don't think the `at @s` is necessary in the first command

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

Repeating command block:

```
execute as @e at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:block name run kill @s
```

If you want certain blocks to kill one type of player and other blocks to kill other types of players you could just fill in teams or tags or names, for example:

Repeating command block:

```
execute as @e[Team=red] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:blue_wool run kill @s
```

Or if you only want one type of player to be able to move across the block fill in the same command with a ! in front of the specified player. For example:

Repeating command block:

```
execute as @e[Team=!red] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ minecraft:red_wool run kill @s
```

Comment: If the execute command isn't working try typing: "gamerule commandblockoutput true" into the chat